# Do you "compare eggs with prunes"?

Tags: idioms

Just come across the eggs/prunes bit in a book. Is "to compare eggs with prunes" an idiomatic expression meaning "to juxtapose totally different things", or just a licencia poetica by the author?

Comment: It's certainly not common.

Comment: "compare eggs with prunes" gives no results in Google so I don't think it's an idiom.

Comment: Never heard of it, the author must've made his/her own version of "to compare apples and oranges".

Comment: Not if I can help it …

Comment: @jules, can you provide the source?  Thanks.

Comment: @Michael Owen Sartin. It's "Putinism" by van Herpen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it is idiomatic of comparing things that cannot be compared.

Much more common though is *comparing apples with oranges*.

Comment: It's a metaphor, but if it's the authors own invention it can't be an idiom. (Not unless it catches on.)

Comment: Am I right thinking the "eggs vs prunes" metaphor seems "stronger" than "apples vs oranges"? The latter are both fruit...

Comment: jules, it's just weird.

Answer (score 1):

Also bear in mind that eggs supposedly give you constipation whereas prunes are well known for their laxative effect. So the author is not only comparing two things that cannot be compared, s/he may be drawing attention to the opposite effects of two substances/situations. Hard to say without the full context.

Comment: Eggs give *me* gas.  I don't think the gastrointestinal effect is what the author was going for . . .

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/157557/59527 Seemed a good fit for the site.

Comment: Ironic "thumbs up" ;) Actually, apples give me diarrhea, while oranges give me zilch. Work with that :)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't call it licencia poetica as the author hasn't changed any fact nor used improper grammar. The author has simply imagined eggs and prunes as extremes and used it as an idiom.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did use the term right.

Comment: I never said you didn't. Hope you didn't take it the wrong way

Comment: No, of course not. I actually had to refer to the origianal definition to make sure I was right. Which served me right :)

Comment: Would this be a case of licencia poetica?

Comment: Seems like it would fit the definition - "alteration of the conventions of language, or rewording of pre-existing text"

Comment: What would you put this under? Its not distorted fact, nor a case of wrong grammar.

Comment: Convention lies at the heart of idiom. An idiom is a convention of language at work. The original idiom has apples vs oranges. The author replaced the fruit with other groceries, while retaining the idiom's structure. In my book, that's "alteration". Moreover, the neo-idiom is a case of rewording as the meaning is - to an extent - the same.

Comment: Since we have established that it is not an idiom, can't we just classify this usage as a metaphor. In that case, why call it an "alteration" of the original idiom? Just a thought.

Comment: I'm afraid all we've established is that it's not an EXISTING idiom. An idiom, nevertheless. It's hardly a metaphor as the groceries mean what they mean, only. It's an "alteration" as the meaning is the same, and so is the structure.